# Spring pagination is not working in DB2

Tags: spring-boot, db2, spring-data-jpa

I am having thousands of records in Database. I want to display the record using pagination in spring. I am able to fetch the first set of data but while fetching the second set of data, I am facing the issue.

I am using spring boot 1.5.8 Release and DB2 database version 11 and platform Z/OS with driver version 4.23

I tried with custom dialect also based on the reference:
[Issue with Spring data jpa Db2 pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199505/issue-with-spring-data-jpa-db2-pagination/40677260#40677260)

but still I am facing the same issue. Could you please help me with this.

below given the details:

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.test.batch.DB2ZOSDialect
```

DB2ZOSDialect.java:

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect;

public class DB2ZOSDialect extends DB2Dialect {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsSequences() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSequenceNextValString(String sequenceName) {
        return "select nextval for " + sequenceName + " from sysibm.sysdummy1";
    }

    @Override
    public String getCreateSequenceString(String sequenceName) {
        return "create sequence " + sequenceName + " as integer start with 1 increment by 1 minvalue 1 nomaxvalue nocycle nocache"; //simple default settings..
    }

    @Override
    public String getDropSequenceString(String sequenceName) {
        return "drop sequence " + sequenceName + " restrict";
    }

    @Override
    public String getQuerySequencesString() {
        return "select name from sysibm.syssequences";
    }

    @Override
    public String getForUpdateString() {
        return " WITH RS USE AND KEEP EXCLUSIVE LOCKS";
    }

}
```

Service:

```
public void fetchDetails() {
    for(int pageCount=0; pageCount < pageTotalCount; pageCount++) {
        Page<com.test.Item> db2Data = db2Repository
                .findByIdIn(new ArrayList<Integer>(Constant.LIST), new PageRequest(pageCount, 10));
        System.out.println("db2Data :"+db2Data.getContent().size());
    }
}
```

Error:

```
15:42:28,990 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: select item0_.id as t1_1 from itm item0_ where item0_.id in (?) fetch first 10 rows only
db2Data :10
15:55:37,270 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) Hibernate: select * from ( select inner2_.*, rownumber() over(order by order of inner2_) as rownumber_ from ( select item0_.id as t1_1 from itm item0_ where item0_.id in (?) fetch first 20 rows only ) as inner2_ ) as inner1_ where rownumber_ > 10 order by rownumber_
15:55:37,744 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) SQL Error: -199, SQLState: 42601
15:55:37,746 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=OF;;??( [ DESC ASC NULLS RANGE CONCAT || / MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND, DRIVER=4.18.60
15:55:37,747 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) SQL Error: -516, SQLState: 26501
15:55:37,748 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-516, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.18.60
15:55:37,749 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) SQL Error: -514, SQLState: 26501
15:55:37,749 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLN200C1, DRIVER=4.18.60
15:55:40,031 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) SQL Warning Code: 4223, SQLState: null
15:55:40,031 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-2) Origination unknown: [10228][11541][4.18.60] Security exceptions occurred while loading driver. ERRORCODE=4223, SQLSTATE=null
15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) 2017-12-14 15:55:40{EST} [default task-2] ERROR o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/copyAllItem] due to exception [could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet]

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy281.findByIdIn(Unknown Source)

15:55:40,049 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at com.test.ItemServiceImpl.copyAllItem(ItemServiceImpl.java:308)

15:55:40,050 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at com.test.ItemController.copyAllItem(ItemController.java:70)

15:55:40,050 INFO  [stdout] (default task-2)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like the cursor is not scrollable.  Configuration issue maybe.

Comment: Are you using the correct dialect? DB2 on Z/OS isn't just DB2 you need a special dialect for this. And also it matters which driver you use... I recall paging on DB2 on z/OS being a PITA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch the Data from DB2 and save in MongoDB using Spring Batch without metadata tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671836/fetch-the-data-from-db2-and-save-in-mongodb-using-spring-batch-without-metadata)

Comment: M. Deinum I changed the driver to 4.23 version and for dialect, I have used the below URL: https://github.com/ManyDesigns/Portofino/blob/master/portofino-db2/src/main/java/com/manydesigns/portofino/database/dialects/DB2ZOSDialect.java. But still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem, I have the same issue